# Using encrypted cookies and a session store to secure requests

Tags: node.js, security, session, cookies, express

I've recently noticed that an application I'm consulting on is utilizing unencrypted cookies. The front end (Angular) regularly uses the following to extract the user id:

```
var user_id = JSON.parse($cookies.userdata).id;
```

I imagine an unsavory visitor could continuously use their browser to change their id and access resources they shouldn't. This is a huge red flag and I could use some help shoring this up. [This looks like a solid enough guide](https://stormpath.com/blog/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-node-dot-js-sessions/), but I haven't quite wrapped my mind around the different pieces.

1. What exactly is stored in the cookie if I use Mozilla's client-session? Anything I want? I have API routes such as `GET /api/v1/user/:user_id` to return information about a user. If the cookie is encrypted on the browser I'll lose the ability to access the current `user_id` and make this API call. What would be my plan of action? Create a proxy server-side to this API that will first unencrypt the cookie, extract the `user_id`, and *then* call `GET /api/v1/user/:user_id`? The API routes are protected by a function that checks is `req.isAuthenticated() === true`, if that helps at all.
2. Given the above, at what point does session come into play? Assume I'm storing user sessions in MongoDB. We know that cookies can only store 4kb, but what if that's enough? What kind of data *should* be stored in the cookie and what kind of data should be stored in the user's session?

Your answers will go a LONG way towards clearing up some concepts that have been a bit of a black box to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What exactly is stored in the cookie if I use Mozilla's
>   client-session? Anything I want?

Yes - any values are encrypted and authenticated, meaning that they cannot be tampered on the client. Basically, when storing anything sensitive client side you want the data to be tamperproof, and optionally confidential too. Authenticating the data with a hashing algorithm like HMAC over SHA-256 prevents tampering, but does not prevent the end user from viewing the value. Encrypting with an algorithm such as AES-128 too, prevents even the end user from viewing the data.

In the case of a username, you would probably only want *integrity* (i.e. making it tamper proof). This will prevent your user from changing it, but your `user_id` calls would still be able to read the value. It is not clear whether Mozilla's client-session supports authentication only. I would be tempted to use [JSON Web Tokens](http://jwt.io/) instead, which does.

> Given the above, at what point does session come into play?

I would use session for storing information that is not required to be client-side at all. As you say, cookies have a size limit. Session makes more sense for large data as the cookie value is sent to the server on *every* request. If you have a large amount of data set in cookies, you will be decreasing the performance of your site for those users with large cookies.

Answer (score 2):

Try to work on one thing at a time or you'll lose your mind! :)

The client can always change anything they want on the client. It doesn't matter. The server matters. The server must use session cookies securely. Read [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet).

The session cookie value doesn't need to be encrypted, it just needs to be long and random so it's very slow and hard to guess it. However, the connection between the browser and server should be encrypted (use HTTPS).

If the client has userId 4, and can successfully request data from /foo/userId/5 then this is bad. But this has nothing to do with cookies and everything to do with [Access Control](https://gist.github.com/facultymatt/6370903) on the server.

Cookie size is mostly irrelevant. You should store as little information in cookies as necessary. Store session data in session (web server memory). Store longer term data in the database.

Comment: Recommend for the poster to also read the following OWASP Top 10 vulnerabilities: [Broken Authentication and Session Management](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A2-Broken_Authentication_and_Session_Management), [Missing Function Level Access Control](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A7-Missing_Function_Level_Access_Control), [Insecure Direct Object References](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A4-Insecure_Direct_Object_References).  I'm quite sure he has all of them.  Protection must be on server side, not client side.